# How to turn a bootstrap table to single cells and back

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I am trying to make a bootstrap table like this that can transform to a cell view like google drive does.

So it would take all the data from one row and put it in a single cell.

from:
[image]

to

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution but I still need to make it work with bootstrap.

The cards all work on a table instead of using divs and can be turned back to a table by removing the cell class

https://codepen.io/isethi/pen/VzwYbm

```
this is because stackoverflow doesn't allow links to codepen.io without some code lol
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if this answer suits your needs @isethi
https://codepen.io/rickydam/pen/GvRRej/left/

---

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Item1</td>
    <td>Item2</td>
    <td>Item3</td>
    <td>Item4</td>
    <td>Item5</td>
    <td>Item6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**CSS**

```
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  display: block;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  td {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
```